# Google Analytics & Social Media Campaigns

Tags: google-analytics

I've been struggling for some time to get an answer, and still can't find it out on the web. I would like to to a seemingly simple thing:
1) Facebook page A sends me some visitors through a link to MYPAGE.com/?utm_campaign=mycampaign& etc. etc.
2) I count the unique page views (not users) received from people that have clicked this link, and no other visits are counted as being part of these (e.g. direct visits of someone recurring that has first come across to the site through that campaign should **not** be included in the count)

This way, I'd like to monitor exactly the unique page views coming from **different** facebook pages which I have a partnership with. And another thing I cannot figure is: how do I make this work on subdomains too?

Best regards

Comment: There is definitely a possibility of getting these data using segments or filter. For example, you can set a segment of visitors based  following conditions:
exclude visitors with campaign == mycampaign and include visitors with source == facebook. But please clarify what reports you're going to run so I can provide you with an accurate suggestion on segments

Comment: I'd like to obtain the unique pageviews coming from a specific campaign, only if they click through a link that has utm parameters with such campaign (I noticed it counts also visits from users that previously clicked the campaign and then return through a normal link to the site, and it's not ok). To clarify, however, for example, if I publish another link on the same fb page with the same campaign, it's ok to recount the new unique pageviews coming from the clicks on this link.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** - You need to have different `utm_campaign` values for each Facebook page.

**Step 2** - Create Google Analytics segment for that specific campaign.

*Use "Filter Sessions" as you only want the sessions that came straight from Facebook.*

[image]

**Step 3** - Use Behaviour -> Site Content reports to see which pages those users visited.

Comment: Thank you. To avoid counting direct visits coming from users that previously clicked such campaign, I tried to set the campaign timeout to 1 day. Is it ok?

Comment: You don't need a timeout. If they come directly to your site they will be counted as "direct". Every session can have only one origin.